# Audit logging using Owin/Katana middleware

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I am trying to write an Owin middleware to create auditlogs for the webapi calls. I can see I have all the details I need to log, however as part of the requirement I also need to inspect the webapi POST and PUT request body parameters and log some of the information if they exist. Hypothetically, zipcode from the below post body.
Ex.

POST api/customer

Body

```
{
  "name": "ABCD",
  "address": "123 Main St.",
  "zipcode": 22034
}
```

Is there a way I can get that from context.Request? if not are there any other ways to get those inside the Middleware?